# how to extract the nth occurrence of a pattern from a zsh variable?

Tags: zsh

I have a variable separated by underscores that encodes different bits of information, for example:

```
my_variable="john_smith_cambridge_MA_65_male"
```

If `location` should be a combination of the third and fourth fields, I guess I could do

```
location=${(j._.)${${(s._.)my_variable}[3,4]}}
echo $location # cambridge_MA
```

but I'm wondering if there is simpler syntax than splitting and then joining.

**EDIT**: After some research, I've found I could use the backreferences flag `(#b)`

```
if [[ $my_variable == (#b)([^_]#)_([^_]#)_([^_]#)_([^_]#)_([^_]#)_([^_]#) ]]; then
    echo ${my_variable[$mbegin[3], $mend[4]]} # cambridge_MA
fi
```

although setting up that long regex seems a little cumbersome.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Splitting and joining seems the clearest method to me. You have one operation to specify how to break up the string, and one operations to specify which fields to keep.

If you're going to use multiple fields, do the split once and for all into an array.

```
details=("${(@s:_:)my_variable}")
location=${(j:_:)details[3,4]}
```

To extract a field in a fixed position, you can also use prefix and suffix stripping:

```
city=${${my_variable#*_*_}%%_*}
```

But that's two operations already just to extract one field, and it doesn't generalize cleanly to multiple consecutive fields unless you know the number of fields, in which case you can strip the suffix in the same way you strip the prefix.

```
location=${${my_variable#*_*_}%_*_*}
```

While you can use the `I` parameter expansion flag to combine the two in a simple search, this requires you to anchor the search at a separator. This works, but it's a lot more cumbersome than splitting and joining.

```
setopt extended_glob
echo ${${(MSI:2:)my_variable##_[^_]##_[^_]##}#_}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think splitting into an array was an important bit that I was missing